# SQL и новый хостинг

Tags: joomla, mysql

новый хостинг, импортировал БД которая взята с моего старого сайта, импорт совершил успешно, создал нового пользователя и так далее. 
но сайт не работает пишет следующее 
Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL
вопрос: 
кто нить может сказать где есть "рассшифровка" файла configuration от joomla
что в этом файле где находиться, где название БД, пароль БД, логины как изменить и тд.

Comment: Версия джумлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для переноса сайта тебе хватит этих параметров

```
public $dbtype = 'XXXX'; (тип БД)
public $host = 'XXXX'; хост на хостинге(обычно localhost)
public $user = 'XXXX'; пользователь БД
public $password = 'XXXX'; пароль от БД
public $db = 'XXXX'; название БД
public $dbprefix = 'XXX'; префикс таблиц
```

Comment: По-моему там ещё должна быть директива, указывающая путь к папке системы, или я ошибаюсь.

Comment: нету такой